# Ajuda em espaçamento com menu

Tags: html, css

Bom eu estou tentando fazer um menu onde tenha, inicio / sobre / loja  e depois um espaço e o "buscar" e  outro espaço e um login/cadastro, mas não estou conseguindo.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
<header>
<div class="logobg"><img src="images/logosecure.png"></div> 
<div class="menubarr">
<nav class="menubarr">
<ul>
<a href="#"><li>Inicio</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Sobre</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Loja</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Contato</li></a>
</ul>
</nav>

<nav class="buscar">
<ul>
<a href="#"><li>Buscar</li></a>
</ul>
</nav>

<nav class="log">
<ul>
<a href="#"><li>Cadastrar</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Login</li></a>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</header>
```

css:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}
section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: #ccc;
}
footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logobg{
    width: 1280px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}

.logobg img{
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
}

 .menubarr{
    width: 1280px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: #000;
}

.menubarr nav ul li{
    background: #000;
    color:#fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

 .menubarr nav ul li:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

como está no momento :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer isso:

Em uma div que englobe todos os `<ul>`, defina um nome de classe ('bloco-menu', no caso):

```
<div class='bloco-menu'>

<nav class="menubarr">
<ul>
<a href="#"><li>Inicio</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Sobre</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Loja</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Contato</li></a>
</ul>
</nav>

<nav class="buscar">
<ul>
<a href="#"><li>Buscar</li></a>
</ul>
</nav>

<nav class="log">
<ul>
<a href="#"><li>Cadastrar</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Login</li></a>
</ul>
</nav> 

</div>
```

Após isso, no CSS, faça assim:

```
   .bloco-menu{
    display: flex;
}

li{
    display: inline-flex;

}
ul{
    padding-left: 1px;
}
```

A propriedade display: `inline-block` que fará com que eles fiquem um ao lado do outro.

Obs: o `padding` do `<ul>` é opcional, eu coloquei pois os `<ul>´s` possui um padding-left (espaçamento á esquerda) padrão de aproximadamente 5px, criando um espaço em branco entre cada `ul`, caso esses estejam lado a lado.

Comment: Vlw manooo mt obrigado funcionou, e caso eu queria dar um margin ou padding não sei qual dos dois utilizar para afastar uma ul da outra? Sem ter que usar o float:right.

Comment: Use o 'padding-left' para diminuir os espaçamentos...

Comment: opa silva eu posso editar e fazer mais uma pergunta agora a dúvida é como eu consigo deixar uma div com um fundo e dentro dessa div tenha um form que fique responsive 1280 e centralizado?

Comment: vc poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Cara, nas propriedades CSS dessa div, tente colocar: { display: flex; align-itens: center;  justify-contents: center; }

Comment: @GabrielCosta deixa eu te dar uma dica. Evite fazer várias perguntas dentro de uma pergunta só. Agora que essa parte da dúvida foi esclarecida não tem problema vc abrir outra pergunta com a nova dúvida. Assim vc evita que o autor da resposta altere a resposta original que é a resposta que responde a pergunta original. Então se tiver outra dúvida basta abrir outra pergunta, simples assim. É só uma dica para orientar-los a usar melhor o StackOverflow ok.

Comment: @hugocsl opa tranquilo.